# Vue - Passing component data to view

Tags: vue.js, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hi I'm looking at Vue and building a website with a Facebook login. I have a Facebook login component, which works, although I'm having difficulty making my acquired fbid, fbname, whatever available to my Vues outside the component. Acknowledged this most likely this is a 101 issue, help would be appreciated.

I've tried the global "prototype" variable and didn't manage to get that working. How's this done?

Code below:

main.js

```
new Vue({
    router, 
    render: h => h(App),
    vuetify: new Vuetify()
}).$mount('#app')
```

App.vue

```
...

import FacebookComp from './components/FacebookComp.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    FacebookComp
  },

...
}
```

Component - FacebookComp.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="facebookcomp">

    <facebook-login class="button"
      appId="###"
      @login="checkLoginState"
      @logout="onLogout"
      @get-initial-status="checkLoginState">
    </facebook-login>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

//import facebookLogin from 'facebook-login-vuejs';
//import FB from 'fb';

export default {
  name: 'facebookcomp',
  data: {
    fbuserid: "string"
  },
  methods: {
    checkLoginState() {
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        fbLoginState=response.status;
      });
      if(fbLoginState === 'connected' && !fbToken){
        fbToken = FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
        FB.api('/me', 'get',  { access_token: fbToken, fields: 'id,name' }, function(response) {

          fbuserid=response.id;

        });
      }
    },
...
}
```

VIEW - view.vue

```
...

export default {
    name: 'view',
    data: function() { 
        return { 
      someData: '',
  },
  mounted() {
    alert(this.fbloginId); //my facebook ID here
  },


...
}
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to pass data FacebookComp.vue to View.vue?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have all these props from FB login available throughout your whole app, I strongly suggest using [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/). If you are not familiar with state management in nowadays SPAs, you basically have global container - state. You can change it only via functions called mutations (synchronous). However, you cannot call them directly from your component. That's what functions called actions (asynchronous) are for. The whole flow is: actions => mutations => state. Once you have saved your desired data in state, you can access it in any of your vue component via functions called getters.

Another option, in case you just need the data visible in your parent only, is to simply emit the data from FacebookComp.vue and listen for event in View.vue. Note that to make this work, FacebookComp.vue has to be a child of View.vue. For more info about implementation of second approach, please look at [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events).